# Unable to translate site analytics related words

Tags: bug, localization, site-analytics

There are no sentences to translate for the following words related to the [site analytics](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics/traffic-sources) chart:

- referring
- search
- direct

> [image: site analytics chart]